# htaccess RewriteRule issue with UTF 8 Encoded query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, prestashop

We have a Prestashop based eCommerce website and is enabled with friendly urls.

The url with a query string like this is working fine.
http://www.mywebsite.com/en/validation?response_text=test

Query string with UTF 8 encoded string is not validated and throwing 404 page error.
http://www.mywebsite.com/en/validation?response_text=PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4mVxdWVzdCB4%0AbWxuczp4PSJod

How to allow UTF 8 encoded string

htaccess is

```html
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
  </IfModule>

 AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
 AddType font/ttf .ttf
 AddType font/otf .otf
 AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|svg)$">
 Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 - maybe try adding it on the top of .htaccess. BTW the string you are showing doesnt' have utf-8 specific characters, looks like a latin1 string to me "http://www.mywebsite.com/en/validation?response_text=PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4mVxdWVzdCB4%0AbWxuczp4PSJod"

Comment: Thanks for your reply Muhammed. I tried AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 already but no luck. The string is URL encoded with UTF-8.